# select all checkboxes in FooTable with pagination and filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

I am currently working on a FooTable project where I am trying to create a 'select all' checkbox. I have run in to two issues and I cannot figure out how to proceed;

1. I can select all items, either ALL items (irrespective of filtering)
   or just the items on the page.
2. I can get all the rows to show up, and select, but It will not filter.
3. I can apply a filter, and still selects all rows.

*What I am looking for* is a way to only select the filtered rows checkboxes, even if the rows are on different pages. I figured a cheaky way to accomplish this would be:

1. increase `pageSize` to more than the amount of filtered rows
2. select all checkboxes in shown rows
3. revert back to OG `pageSize`

```html
<table class="tg" data-paging="true" data-paging-size="3" data-filtering="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Select All:<input type="checkbox" class="check-all"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check-one"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check-one"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check-one"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check-one"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check-one"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check-one"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check-one"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check-one"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check-one"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check-one"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check-one"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.tg').footable();

  function changePageSize(qs_table, num_rows_page) {
    let newSize = num_rows_page;
    FooTable.get(qs_table).pageSize(newSize);
  }

  function checkedAll(qs_table, qs_checkbox, num_column, checked) {
    var ft = FooTable.get(qs_table)
    ft.pageSize(11);
    FooTable.init(qs_table);
    let rows = ft.rows.all;
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
      row.draw(); //REQUIRED for js rendering row, else selected only chockboxes on the active page
      $(qs_checkbox, row.cells[num_column].$el[0]).prop('checked', checked);
    });
  }

  $(document).on("change", ".check-all", function() {
    checkedAll(".tg", ".check-one", 2, $(this).prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

Here is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/T3DDIE_B3AR/pe2usL5r/

Comment: `I am looking for a way to only select the filtered rows checkboxes, even if the rows are on different pages` this will be a problem as if the rows are on pages which aren't being displayed they don't exist, and you cannot select something that doesn't exist. You'd need to restructure the logic so that there's a flag which is sent to the server to say 'perform this action on everything' as well as the individual checkboxes which select the visible elements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, yeah, that is why I was trying to be cheeky and reinitialize the table with all rows showing post filtering on page, then select only those showing rows, followed by reimplementing the original `pageSize`